# Python subprocess: Windows command line safety

Tags: python, windows

The idea is to execute code on Windows via Python's `subprocess.Popen`, but, in the command I'm executing, there's also a password which I need to keep secure.

Does Windows store (somewhere, e.g. logs) commands executed this way via Python?

Normally, I would execute such a command via standard Windows command line like `net use`, but now I moved it to my Python script, and because it contains a password, I want to keep it as secure as possible.

Comment: It's possible for other processes owned by the user or an administrator to read the command-line string of a process. Various tools that manage processes implement this, such as Task Manager and Process Explorer.

Comment: If you control the implementation of the executed program, you could have it use the credential-manager API, in which passwords are securely stored in a user's vault.